# What are move-aware containers? C++

Tags: c++, c++11

What are move-aware containers in C++? I know std::vector is a move-aware container. But I don't know what move-aware means.

Comment: Where did you see this term? I can only find "allocator-aware" in the C++ standard.

Comment: you mean like struct with a bool indicating if its been changed?

Comment: From the cppreference, [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), "as the element type in move-aware containers, such as std::vector..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *move-aware container* occurs in this context:

> `std::unique_ptr` is commonly used to manage the lifetime of objects, including:
>   ...
>   * as the element type in move-aware containers, such as `std::vector`, which hold pointers to dynamically-allocated objects (e.g. if polymorphic behavior is desired)

It means that the container knows how to handle move-only types. `std::unique_ptr` is a move-only type: it cannot be copied. This implies that a container holding objects of move-only types must itself be move-only.

Comment: Is there any stl container which is not move-aware?

Comment: In a strict sense, no STL container is move-aware, but that's terminology. The STL was one of the contributors to the Standard Library in 1998, and wasn't maintained as a separate library afterwards. Compare Boost, which contributes since C++11 and is still actively maintained. That said, `std::basic_string<Ch>` isn't going to bother - moving a `char` or `wchar_t` is the same as copying it.

Comment: @miāo - you've missed MSalters (somewhat hypertechnical) point: there is no STL any more, although many people seem to use "STL" to refer to the C++ Standard Library, or perhaps a subset of it.